# OpenTok (iOS) - Best practice to start a video chat when one participant has the app in background

Tags: ios, swift, opentok, tokbox

We have Participant A and Participant B.

1. A triggers `sessionDidConnect`
2. A triggers session `streamCreated`
3. A pauses the app. The app is running in background
4. B triggers `sessionDidConnect`
5. B triggers session `streamCreated`

When A brings the app to foreground, then the connection and stream get destroyed. I would like to understand what we are doing wrong.

When is the best moment to call the following methods?

- `session.publish(publisher, ...)`
- `session.subscribe(subscriber, ...)`

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

In order to prevent your application from disconnecting from the session in background mode, please do the following:

- Open XCode
- Click on **Capabilities** and turn on **Background Modes**[image]
- Check the **Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture option**[image]
- Rebuild the application.

After making these changes, your application will stay connected to the session, publish audio, and stay subscribed to the streams in the session when in background mode, but you will not be able to publish video until the application is brought to the foreground.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this @manik. The "Audio Airplay and Picture in Picture" option in Background Mode capabilities are already set up like you described. I followed your documentation from https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/background-state.html when I initially set up the SDK. Any other idea?

Comment: @ThibaultLeConte Thanks for letting me know. Can you create an issue in the sample repo so we can investigate a solution for you? https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples-swift

Comment: Thx for your help on investigating this. I created the issue: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples-swift/issues/68